# Java and 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn Java's threads in order to do an assignment, but I do not understand how I can make each thread to do its own code. I also get an error:

```
Program.java:1: error: Program is not abstract and does not override abstract me
thod run() in Runnable
public class Program implements Runnable {
       ^
1 error
```

Because it is required by the assignment, I have to do everything within the same file, so I tried the code below:

```
public class Program implements Runnable {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread () {
        public void run () {
            System.out.println("test1");
        }
};

Thread thread2 = new Thread () {
    public void run () {
        System.out.println("test2"); 
        }
    };

    public void main (String[] args) {
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Could you please fix it for me and show how to have 2 threads which do different tasks from each other? I have already seen examples that print threads' names, but I did not find them helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: looks more like you are learning java. Just remove the `implements Runnable`from Program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Program` class is defined as implementing the `Runnable` interface.  It therefore must override and implement the `run()` method:

```
public void run () {
}
```

Since your two `Thread` objects are using anonymous *inner* `Runnable` classes, you do not need and your should remove the `implements Runnable` from your `Program` class definition.

```
public class Program {
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("test1");
            }
        };

        Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("test2");
            }
        };
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
}
```

Or you can create a separate class implementing `Runnable` and ovverriding method `run()`.
Then in `main` method create an instance of `Thread` with you class object as argument :

```
class SomeClass implements Runnable {
@Override
run(){
...
}
}
```

and in main:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new SomeClass());
```

Comment: Well, I am not sure what I should use. I have read there are 2 ways: by extending Thread and implementing Runnable. All I need is to have separate code for each thread. I do not want them to do the same thing.

Comment: so you ca extend the functionallity of Thread or just implement one method from Runnable. You can use the second option to create an anonymous classes:
`Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
  });`

Answer (score 0):

When you `implement` an `interface` (such as `Runnable`) you **must** implement its methods, in this case `run`.

Otherwise for your app to compile and run just erase the `implements Runnable` from your class declaration:

```
public class Program {
    public void main (String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread () {
            public void run () {
                System.out.println("test1");
            }
        };    

        Thread thread2 = new Thread () {
            public void run () {
                System.out.println("test2");
            }
        };
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: thread1 and thread2 are not static so they cannot be called in static context of method `main` which is obviously must be static.